# One to one relation in EF Core using FluentAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-one

I have implemented a 1 to 1 relation in my database but the reference to the FK object is null.

I will show you some code as it will be easier to explain.

I have the following models:

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public RefreshToken RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

RefreshToken.cs

```
public class RefreshToken : Trackable
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }


    public int UserRef { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the onModelCreating function I have defined the following using FluentAPI

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(a => a.RefreshToken)
            .WithOne(b => b.User)
            .HasForeignKey<RefreshToken>(b => b.UserRef);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RefreshToken>().HasKey(u => u.UserRef);
```

Everything in the database is created as I expected.

If I request a User using the following code

```
        _dbContext.Set<User>().Find(id);
```

the property RefreshToken is null.

What I am missing something in my code?

Note: If at first I request the RefreshToken and later on the User then the property is correctly set.

Comment: Relationship configuration is ok. What you are missing is [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default eager loading is off in entity framework. Otherwise we would have ended up in fetching huge data set when fetch just one record. 
So if you want to load navigational properties as well with the record, you have to explicitly include them.

```
_dbContext.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
```

> Note: If at first I request the RefreshToken and later on the User
>   then the property is correctly set.

That's because when you load RefreshToken before User, Refreshtoken is cached in the data context. Then when you are fetching the User, EF set the Refreshtoken using the object in cache. It is not fetching Refresh Token along with the user record.